# Нужен совет по интеграции в WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Есть три статические страницы и на каждой из них есть три вот такие афишки. Нужно интегрировать эти афишки, чтобы была возможность в каждой менять изображение и текст.

Правильно ли будет **такой подход:** я создал в **ACF** три группы полей под каждую афишку, потом создал одну запись "Афиши" и там все эти поля заполнил. Теперь нужно эту запись через **PHP** вставить во все три статические страницы. Если такой подход правильный, подскажите код чтобы определенную запись вставить в страницы?

Или все это как-то иначе будет правильно делать? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: три статических странички, каждая со своим шаблоном?

Comment: Так запись или страница? В контексте вопроса это не особо важно, но путаться не нужно. И где вывести то, что на скрине - на странице/записи или где-то в др месте?

Comment: Судя по кнопке "забронировать" на сайте должен быть реализован функционал мероприятий. Плагины, которые это делают могут и "афишки" внедрять. Но даже если и нет, то в любом случае нужно отталкиваться от этого, а не о вёрстки и вывода того, чего нет.

Comment: Спасибо, я афиши делал как запись, и вывод нужно делать на страницах, у каждой свой шаблон

Comment: Ну если так.. На страницах просто 3 произвольных поля с адресами "зависимых" постов. Лучше оформить метабоксы с выбором оных. В шаблоне уже подтягивать анонс и миниатюру. Но я бы рекомендовал подобрать готовый плагин. "Просто запись" для мероприятия не то.  совсем не то.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[get_fields([$post_id]);](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_fields/)** - вытаскивает на свет кастомные поля, соответствующие посту/странице/т.д.

`$acfs = get_fields(7);` - вернёт все `cf` для поста `id = 7;`  в форме ассоциативного массива `"Field Name" => "value"`.