# Вывод записи в странице WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

Подскажите, пожалуйста код. Вот, например, я создал запись с определенной рубрикой, применил ей свой шаблон с HTML кодом. Потом делаю по этому коду вывод записи на странице:

```
<?php
if ( have_posts() ) : // если имеются записи в блоге.
    query_posts('cat=12');   // указываем ID рубрик, которые необходимо вывести.
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();  // запускаем цикл обхода материалов блога
        ?>

<?php the_content();

    endwhile;  // завершаем цикл.
endif;
/* Сбрасываем настройки цикла. Если ниже по коду будет идти еще один цикл, 
чтобы не было сбоя. */
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Так вот, как сделать чтобы вместо вывода контента записи:

```
<?php the_content();
```

на страницу вставлялася какая-то секция с HTML кода шаблона записи. Или, вставлялся полностью HTML код шаблона записи (если шаблон имеет не полноценную HTML структуру, а, скажем, содержит только какой-то HTML блок)

Comment: Это ты не шаблон применил, а сделал выборку из одно рубрики.  См [раз](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#single-post) и [два](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/#creating-page-templates-for-specific-post-types)

Comment: А можешь, пожалуйста, подсказать, как возможно HTML код шаблона записи вставить в определенное место в шаблоне странице? (или какой-то один блок с HTML кода шаблона записи)

Comment: Непонял.. Попробуй сформулировать  понятно (какова конечная цель?)

Comment: Смотри, есть три страницы, с разными шаблонами. В каждой из них есть одинаковая секция "Афиши" (в этой секции три блока, это три афишки). И эту секцию нужно интегрировать, чтобы клиент мог менять текс, фото и т.д.). Я поступил так. Создал запись под эту секцию "Афиши", применил ей свой шаблон с нужным HTML кодом, текст и фото в шаблоне заменил полями плагина ACF, и заполнил эти поля в записи. Теперь мне нужно шаблон этой записи, то есть HTML код, вставить во все три страницы, там где должна быть секция "Афиши". Но как это сделать? Или я что-то путаю и это совсем не так делается?)

Comment: Это всё [тот же вопроc](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/760237/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b2-wordpress)? Отвечая в комментах обращайся по нику через @. (напр @SeVlad) Тогда человек получит сообщение. Без этого получит только автор вопроса\ответа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно создать блок с афишами как отдельную страницу и вставлять этот блок в другие страницы.

Создайте страницу с нужным контентом HTML (афиши в вашем примере) встроенными средствами WordPress. Назовите ее, например, Posters. Установите странице Posters видимость "Личное", чтобы избежать прямого доступа к ней.

Добавьте такой код в functions.php вашей темы:

```
// Add shortcode to output html block from page containing template
function html_block_shortcode( $atts ) {
    $p = get_page_by_title( $atts['title'] );
    if ( empty( $p ) ) {
        return '';
    }

    $id = apply_filters( 'wpml_object_id', $p->ID, 'post' );
    $p = get_post( $id );

    return do_shortcode( $p->post_content );
}
add_shortcode('block', 'html_block_shortcode');
```

У вас появился шорткод для вывода любой страницы по её заголовку, например:

```
[block title="posters"]
```

или

```
do_shortcode('[block title="posters"]');
```

Такой шорткод выведет содержимое страницы с заголовком "Posters" (даже если её видимость - "Личное").

В коде выше есть фильтр `wpml_object_id` - он выведет страницу с переводом при использовании плагина WPML и ничего не сделает при его отсутствии. Можете смело оставить в своём коде.